# pkg_resources.DistributionNotFound in Ryu-oe

Tags: sdn

My goal is to have a optical LINC switch running and use Ryu-oe to control it.

But I receive the following error when I try to run Ryu-Oe instruction from [this link](https://github.com/o3project/ryu-oe).

Ryu-oe is just ryu controller with some optical extensions.

```
    File "/usr/local/bin/ryu-manager", line 5, in <module>
    from pkg_resources import load_entry_point
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 2749, in <module>
    working_set = WorkingSet._build_master()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 446, in _build_master
    return cls._build_from_requirements(__requires__)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 459, in _build_from_requirements
    dists = ws.resolve(reqs, Environment())
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 628, in resolve
    raise DistributionNotFound(req)
pkg_resources.DistributionNotFound: msgpack-python>=0.4.0
```

Anyone knows how I can solve the error?

Comment: This question is more about installing/running this specific piece of software (or maybe even python) than about network engineering. You probably will get a better answer from the people responsible for building it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok it seems that the problem is solved. To be honest I don't know how it was solved. Here are some of the commands I ran:

Make sure you are in ryu-oe directory.

`sudo -H ./run_tests.sh 
sudo ./run_tests.sh 
sudo -H python ./setup.py install`

and then I ran `sudo ryu-manager ~/ryu-oe/ryu/app/ofctl_rest.py`.

Let me know which one worked for you so that we come up with a better answer.